# Joining three tables in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I am trying to join three tables together and then pull out a specific table but not getting any luck

```rb
@applications_created = FinancialDocument.joins(:loan).joins(:campaign)
@applications_created = FinancialDocument.where(status: ['awaiting_verification', 'rejected', 'verified']).order('id DESC')
@applications_created = @applications_created.where('loan.campaign_id = ?', params[:cid]) if params[:cid].present?
@applications_created = @applications_created.where('loan.campaign_name = ?', params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
```

I just keep getting the error:

```rb
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'loan.campaign_name' in 'where clause': SELECT `financial_documents`.* FROM `financial_documents` WHERE `financial_documents`.`status` IN ('awaiting_verification', 'rejected', 'verified') AND (loan.campaign_name = 'Imagery') ORDER BY id DESC
```

schema.rb

```rb
create_table "loans", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t| ...

create_table "campaigns", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t| ...

create_table "financial_documents", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t| ...
```

loan.rb

```rb
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to  :user
has_many    :financial_documents, dependent: :destroy..
```

financial_document.rb

```rb
class FinancialDocument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :loan
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :campaign ...
```

campaign.rb

```rb
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :loan
```

Comment: What is your table name? Is it `loan` or `loans`?

Comment: Hi yes FinancialDocument, Loan and Campaign

Comment: Not the model names. Please tell me the table name or just update the question with `schema.rb` file

Comment: I see what you mean, I have added the first lines from each model from schema.rb

Comment: So your table name is loans, try changing `loan` to `loans` in your code

Comment: ```@applications_created = FinancialDocument.joins(:loans).joins(:campaigns)``` I'm still getting the same error Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'campaign_name' in 'where clause': SELECT `financial_documents`.* FROM `financial_documents` WHERE `financial_documents`.`status` IN ('awaiting_verification', 'rejected', 'verified') AND (campaign_name = 'Imagery') ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: Update the question with the models and its associations.

Comment: Try changing `@applications_created = @applications_created.where('loan.campaign_name = ?', params[:name]) if params[:name].present?` to `@applications_created = @applications_created.where('loans.campaign_name = ?', params[:name]) if params[:name].present?`

Comment: Did my suggestion worked?